# Как протестировать мобильное приложение под android на большом количестве моделей телефонов?

Tags: android, тестирование

Я занят сложным проектом, связанным со всеми android устройствами, залоченными под конкретного оператора сотовой связи. Приложение необходимо тестировать на как можно большем числе моделей телефонов, но купить все эти модели телефонов не представляется возможным.

Как всё-таки организовать тестирование наиболее эффективно, учитывая ограниченные ресурсы? Например:

- Удобным способом найти больше количество бета-тестировщиков;
- Разместить где-то заказ, который распределят между тестировщиками с нужными телефонами;
- Найти одного поставщика услуг, владеющего большим набором моделей.

Comment: Переформулировал немного вопрос, чтобы его не закрыли. Если где-то соврал, поправляйте. )

Comment: @закрыватели: вполне реальная задача, в какой-то степени стоящая перед каждым разработчиком мобильных приложений. В индустрии наверняка есть принятые способы и best-practice, их вполне можно описать в паре абзацев каждый. Если вопрос начнёт привлекать спам, его можно будет защитить.

Comment: спасибо большое за правку) Все правильно) Да, мне нужны люди, готовые протестировать приложение для разлочки от оператора

Comment: utest.com? возможно, есть русскоязычные аналоги